# What is different between major, minor and beta npm release?

Tags: npm, npm-install, npm-package

I was going through one of the npm dependency and i observed there are multiple major, minor and beta version releases for that dependency. It raises some questions for me which are mentioned below. Could you please help me understand those point?

1. What is difference between Major, Minor and beta version?
2. I have to install or use the dependency in the production. Should I go with latest version that could be beta version or last major version release.